# Redirect to public ELB from AWS ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer, api-gateway

Im trying to redirect a call from api gateway to a public elb in AWS. The ELB is open to the world but I cannot make it work going by the API Gateway.

[API GateWayConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyVYF.png)

I get this response from the postman when I call the events operation
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}

And from AWS test console, Im getting this error:

Wed Jan 17 20:29:12 UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Host name 'public-elb.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.confidential.com)
Wed Jan 17 20:29:12 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 500

I assume that the ELB is reachable because then I change to another random URL, the error code is "Invalid endpoint address".

Why am I getting this error? I only have one certificate and is the same in the url and the elb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is caused by the SSL certificate having the common name "*.confidential.com" and you are redirecting to a different name "public-elb.amazonaws.com"

The solution is to create an ALIAS (preferred) or CNAME record in DNS that maps your domain name to the ELB dns name. Then use that name in your redirect.